# Pass powershell variable accross multiple agents in Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

My release pipeline has two different agents, one **azurehosted** and one **selfhosted**.

In the Azure hosted agent, i'm setting my variable.

Later, in the self hosted agent, i need to read to variable's value.

However, it's not working to share variable values accross the two agents... any idea?

Attachments:

1. Variable declaration
   [image]
2. Variable reading (NOT WORKING)
   [image]

Comment: You should use output variable `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=abc;isOutput=true]123"
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we can use the [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) with `isoutput=true` to pass variable between jobs for YAML pipelines. See [SetVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) and
[Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) for details.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputSauce;isoutput=true]canned goods"
```

But for the classic release pipelines, it’s not supported to pass variables across jobs/stages like YAML.

[image]

In your scenario, across multiple agents means in different jobs. So, it doesn't work.

However, we can use another way to achieve that:

1. Set a release variable in your pipeline.
   [image]
2. Make sure the build service account has the permission to manage the release:
   [image]
3. Enable the option `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` in job
   agent.
   [image]
4. Add a PowerShell task to run a script to update the current release variable value if needed by calling REST API [Releases - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP). You can reference the following PowerShell script to do that.
   [image]
5. Then we can use the updated variable in other jobs across agents.
   [image]

PowerShell script for your reference:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/release/releases/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)?api-version=7.0"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99)"

# Update an existing variable named FOO to its new value 1234
$pipeline.variables.FOO.value = "1234"

#****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 

Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'FOO' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.FOO.value

write-host "=========================================================="
```